# Clarify normalization with two currently living arrangements

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I was reading a document about database normalization: ["Nermalization"](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/20-Nermalisation.html) (sic!).  The only thing that I don't see explained is how to deal with a cat who lives at two locations at the same time, or uses two names at the same time.

Here's an example of what I am dealing with: I have a title that lives with `ContentID` whose recommended distribution seasons are Fall and Spring.

So, do I create a `distribution_recommendation_by_contentID` table in the normalized section of my database?

Comment: ID numbers have nothing to do with normalization. Even Wikipedia's articles on 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, etc., are better than the article you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two values (Fall and Spring). i would not create an extra table for only these two values. Otherwise you need always a join statement to retrive the recommendation information which will effect performance of your database.

If each content has only one distrubution value(like Fall, Spring, etc), it is better to keep in one table.

The other case is that each content have more than one distrubution value. Let's say Title A has two distrubution value Fall and Winter. Than it makes sense to have an extra table to keep these information(distribution_recommendation_by_contentID).

If you have a use case that you need to show available distrubution values, then you can create another table for distrubution values and reference id of distrubution values.

Comment: The table contains more than that.  Fall, Spring, Summer, Winter, a list of holidays, etc.  It's not terribly large, though, and it's pretty static.  What would you recommend?

Comment: If you expand your question or explain a little about your tables and your data that you have, i can expand the answer more detailed

Comment: @wolfpack08 see my comment and expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
lives_with_owner_no from    until   under_the_name
1                   1998    2002    1
3                   2002    NULL    1
2                   1997    NULL    2
3                   1850    NULL    3
3                   1999    NULL    4
2                   2002    2002    4
*3                  2002    *NULL   *5
*2                  2002    *NULL   *5
```

Have multiple null-ending results.

Comment: Forget about the cats. Concrete on your situation